# Sabre SOAP Service class, MessageHeaderValue property

Tags: wcf, soap

I have inherited the responsibility for maintaining our Sabre client, and have a need to update our use of the `TravelItineraryReadRQ` (and, maybe `TravelItineraryReadLLSRQ`) Actions. I am still very new to the Sabre APIs (and relatively inexperienced with WCF and SOAP), and there is one detail that I am seeing in our codebase that concerns me.

Generated from the API's WSDL, our existing code contains the classes `TravelItineraryReadService`, `TravelItineraryReadRQ` and `TravelItineraryReadRS` (and, of course, many others). That's fine.

My predecessor, however, extended `TravelItineraryReadService` by adding a constructor, in which he sets the `MessageHeader` property. I cannot find any code which consumes this property (and it is not an override of a virtual or abstract property defined in `SoapHttpClientProtocol`, the base class). I might ignore this code, therefore, (a) if I didn't suspect that somehow a SOAP wrapper used the values set in the message header and (b) if my predecessor hadn't set it as follows:

```
MessageHeaderValue = MessageHeader.Create(connection, "TravelItineraryReadLLS", "TravelItineraryReadLLSRQ");
```

You'll see that he is using the 'LLS' variant of the API and Action Code, yet the `TravelItineraryReadService` methods consume / return the 'non-LLS' request and result objects.

Our code logs the RQ and RS packets it sends and receives, and we're sending / receiving the 'non-LLS' variants - so perhaps I am worrying over nothing. But, the deadline is looming and I am in the dark about how this code might be influencing things.

If you have any information that would help me understand how `MessageHeaderValue` is used (and, its equivalent is present on many other Sabre XxxService WSDL-Generated classes) that would be very helpful.

If, at the same time, you have similar information about the `SecurityValue` property, that would be good, too.

Comment: Ah, progress! I've discovered that the MessageHeaderValue no longer exists on the higher version of the API I'm trying to migrate to. So, this question is now a waste of time. Sorry about that!